# How to generate entire html content in a single page using ironpdf

Tags: ironpdf

```
        HtmlToPdf Renderer = new HtmlToPdf();
        Renderer.RenderingOptions.Timeout = 60;
        Renderer.RenderingOptions.RenderDelay = 30000;
        Renderer.RenderingOptions.EnableJavaScript = true;
        Renderer.RenderingOptions.PaperOrientation = 
        IronPdf.Rendering.PdfPaperOrientation.Landscape;
        Renderer.RenderingOptions.Title = "Test Iron";
        //Renderer.RenderingOptions.SinglePage = true; // no such setting available
       
        Renderer.RenderingOptions.MarginTop = 10;
        Renderer.RenderingOptions.MarginLeft = 10;
        Renderer.RenderingOptions.MarginRight = 10;
        Renderer.RenderingOptions.MarginBottom = 10;
        Renderer.RenderingOptions.ViewPortWidth = 1080;

        PdfDocument Pdfdocument =
        Renderer.RenderUrlAsPdf("https://localhost:44254/ABC/test.html?gid=21632");

        string fileName = @"C:\Test\testiron.pdf";
        Pdfdocument.SaveAs(fileName);

        Pdfdocument.Dispose();
        Renderer.Dispose();
```

How to generate entire html content in a single page using ironpdf ? I could not find any setting for this.

Comment: At the moment it is not possible to render the URL into one single page without manually changing the paper size Renderer.RenderingOptions.SetCustomPaperSizeInInches(11.7, 68.5)

Answer (score 1):

With IronPdf version **2023.9.8**. You can use the UseContinuousFeedRendering method. The method is intended to creates a single page PDF which will force its entire content's width and height to fit into one page. Suitable forconsumer bill or receipt.

```
ChromePdfRenderer renderer = new ChromePdfRenderer();

renderer.RenderingOptions.PaperFit.UseContinuousFeedRendering(80);
```

Answer (score 0):

U need to change the size of your pdf to the largest paper size.

```
IronPdf.Rendering.PdfPaperSize.DSheet
```

Or

```
IronPdf.Rendering.PdfPaperSize.ESheet
```